# How do I detect a Minecraft banner of a specific color?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'd like to detect a banner of a specific color in various situations: Standing, hanging, dropped, and inside player/entity inventory (as well as in the head slot).

These work:

```
/testfor @e[type=Item] {Item:{id:"minecraft:banner"}}
/testfor @a {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:banner"}]}
```

These don't work:

```
/testfor @e[type=Item] {Item:{id:"minecraft:banner",Damage:0}}
/testfor @e[type=Item] {Item:{id:"minecraft:banner",Base:0}}
/testfor @e[type=Item] {Item:{id:"minecraft:banner"},Damage:0}
/testfor @e[type=Item] {Item:{id:"minecraft:banner"},Base:0}
/testfor @e[type=Item] {Item:{id:"minecraft:banner",tag:{Damage:0}}}
/testfor @e[type=Item] {Item:{id:"minecraft:banner",tag:{Base:0}}}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have read the entire internet and discovered the ways to detect banners with specific base colors. It turns out that I was really close. Here are some examples that are working in 1.8.1:

Test for a placed banner (on the ground) that is Blue colored (`{Base:4}`), and facing north (8):

```
/testforblock 60 14 116 minecraft:standing_banner 8 {Base:4}
```

Test for a placed banner (hanging) that is Blue colored (`{Base:4}`), and facing north (2):

```
/testforblock 48 2 38 minecraft:wall_banner 2 {Base:4}
```

Test for a banner in a player's inventory (note the `4s` means Blue. The `s` is important):

```
/testfor @p {Inventory:[{Slot:103b,id:"minecraft:banner",Damage:4s}]}
```

Test for a banner that has been dropped on the ground that is Blue colored (`Damage:4s`):

```
/testfor @e[type=Item,x=40,y=1,z=40,dx=40,dy=27,dz=80] {Item:{id:"minecraft:banner",Damage:4s}}
```

*Notes:*

- The values for facing didn't appear to be optional in my tests. Without them, the match would simply fail. See all the values for facing [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Banner#Block_data). Please correct me if I'm wrong.
- It's possible to match every detail about the flag, including the patterns, as demonstrated [here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/recent-updates-and-snapshots/2179208-testfor-custom-banner-on-a-players-head?comment=3).
- The banner base color "Damage" or "Base" values are 0-15. `0` being black, `1` being red, etc. etc.

Comment: You have read the ENTIRE internet?

Comment: I tried touse that "Damage:<number>s" and it didn't work. Basicly I'm trying to detect a sunflower, and it's a "double_plant".Please help me too.

Comment: @Tmpod The `Damage` property is a field that Mojang abuses for various purposes, is subject to change, and doesn't work with all blocks. I don't know the answer to your question. So, to prevent your question from dead-ending here, I recommend creating a new question specific to your goals, and just reference this one.